# HashMap have old value around till they stop being referenced

Tags: java, android, concurrency, hashmap

I have a situation where I load some data at application level inside a `HashMap`in my android application. I use one of the entries (with a particular `keyA` in the `HashMap`) in this map to initialise some data inside my `Activity` and this `Activity` hangs around for a while. While the user is on this activity, the `HashMap` from which I referenced the object for `keyA` might change. The code to update the `HashMap` is written by me. When I want to update the `HashMap`, I want to clear the entire `HashMap`(so that its `size()` returns 0) and want to populate everything again. If I call `HashMap.clear()`, would it make the old objects to be garbage collected?

If yes, what is the best way to clear the entire `HashMap` so that I don't loose the old objects if they are being referred to anywhere else in the code. What would be the best to reassign values to the `HashMap` in this case?

PS: I am using `ReentrantReadWriteLock` for maintaining the access if that might help.

Comment: As long as `Activity` has a reference to the object you don't want to go away, it won't go away.

Comment: If you have references to it, it won't be garbage collected. That's how the garbage collector works.

Comment: Thank you for quick comments. I have updated the question to a specific case. Please consider reading it again.

Comment: not clear, what you are asking?

Comment: your updated question is unclear. Anyway, the two first comments give a good hint of what you need to know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I call HashMap.clear(), would it make the old objects to be garbage collected?

No.  No Java object will ever be garbage collected if it is *reachable*.  If there is any reference (or chain of references) that allows your code to access an object, then the object is safe from garbage collection.

Answer (score 1):

> If I call HashMap.clear(), would it make the old objects to be garbage collected?

A `HashMap` is just storing a single reference to an object.  When you call `clear()`, then the object can be gc'd if (and only if) the only reference to the object was the `HashMap`.  If other parts of the code have references to the object then it won't be.  That's how gc works.  `HashMap` isn't magic.

> What would be the best to reassign values to the HashMap in this case?

If you are updating the values in a shared map then your code is going to have to re-get the values from the map whenever they use them – or maybe every so often.  I'd first re-get the value each time you use it and then prove to yourself that it's too expensive before doing anything else.

> PS: I am using ReentrantReadWriteLock for maintaining the access if that might help.

I'd switch to using a `ConcurrentHashMap` and not both with the expense and code maintenance of doing the locking yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to update specifically **keyA** alone then you can use `HashMap.put("keyA","value");`

This will replace the value of **keyA** in the HashMap object with the value you specify, also it will not affect the other values saved in the HashMap object.